# $H\subseteq \cup_{n=1}^\infty G_n$ but there is no $m$ so that $H\subseteq \cup_{n=1}^m G_n$.

Tags: real-analysis

Let $H=\left\{\dfrac{1}{n}:n\in \mathbb{N}\right\}$.

1. Construct a sequence of open sets $G_n$ in $\mathbb{R}$ so that $H\subseteq \cup_{n=1}^\infty G_n$ but there is no $m$ so that $H\subseteq \cup_{n=1}^m G_n$.
2. Show that if $G_n$, $n\in \mathbb{N}$ is any sequence of open sets in $\mathbb{R}$ so that $H\cup\{0\}\subseteq \cup_n^\infty G_n$ then there is $m\in \mathbb{N}$ so that $H\cup\{0\}\subseteq \cup_{n=1}^m G_n$. (Try to avoid using the Heine Borel Theorem.)

For one I have $\left(\dfrac{1}{n+\dfrac{1}{2}},\dfrac{1}{n-\dfrac{1}{2}}\right)$, and for two I believe $\left(-\dfrac{1}{n},1+\dfrac{1}{n}\right)$ works. My question is how to I formally show both of these?

Comment: I think you're missing an $n$ or two in your answer to "1". To prove that first claim, fix a number $m$ and then explicitly find (in terms of $m$) a point of $H$ that is not in there.

Comment: Thank you for noticing the typos. Can $k=\dfrac{2-m}{2m}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The example for the first part you give is correct. To prove it just note that

- each $G_n$ is open,
- one has $1/n \in G_n$ for each $n$ so the inclusion holds,
- however $1/k\notin \cup_{i=1}^m G_m $ for each $k >m$.

For the second part it seems you answer a different question than asked. You need to show something for every possible choice of $G_n$; one example won't cut it.  To show this second part, not that there must be some $G_k$ with $0 \in G_k$. Since $G_k$ is open there is thus some $\epsilon > 0$ such that $(-\epsilon , \epsilon ) \subset G_k$. Thus for all $n > 1/\epsilon$ you have $1/n \in G_k$, and you  just have to deal with the finitely  many remaining terms $1/n$  with $n \le 1/\epsilon$. Those are of course contained in a finite union of the $G_n$. Then put the things together.